# Undo Ubuntu installation

Tags: uninstall, windows-xp

I Installed Ubuntu on a Windows XP computer (completely installed not side by side) I have 1 gb of RAM with a Pentium 4 processor Ubuntu version is 15.04 it runs as slow as heck is there any way to speed up my computer or to revert to windows xp with out the boot disk for XP? I am thinking of getting a SSD though but I have no idea wether to get Sata III or less

Comment: Since Ubuntu no longer has the 2d desktop, it is not a good choice for this pc.  Try Lubuntu, it works well for me on a similar device.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is old and unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

You might check in your BIOS to see if you have a hyperthreading option and if so if it is enabled.  Hyperthreading can give a performance boost, and I believe some of the P4's had hyper-threading technologies.

Even at that, with only 1GB of Ram, it's doable, but you would be better with a lighter desktop environment.  You could try looking up xfce, kde, or even lxde if you need something quite light.  In my opinion with lxde and even a single thread p4 with 1gb of ram it should be usable, depending, of course, what you're using it for.

Ubuntu 16.04 should be out soon, so another thing you could try would be doing a fresh install of server 16.04 minimally when it comes out and installing lxde on top of that.  You should have a fairly stable, quite light installation which can run the most modern programs in the new software center.

Another side note: I would **not** recommend reinstalling XP even if you can get your hands on an old installation : it's support is expired and security is a major risk unless you use it strictly offline.